# Could not rename file /dbfdata/database/com.test.myapp/shared_prefs/cpShared.xml to cpChared.bak

Tags: android

What is the cause of this error and how can it be fixed?

```
Could not rename file /dbfdata/database/com.test.myapp/shared_prefs/cpShared.xml to cpChared.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you use `java.io.File.renameTo`.

If yes, it fails because you try to write to the current directory where you don't have write permission. To avoid this, you have to specify the full target path: `/dbfdata/database/com.test.myapp/shared_prefs/cpChared.bak`